# How to make unique insertion with token

Tags: php, forms, session, token

I would like to prevent double insertion with refresh
but what I did doesn't work!
Where I'm wrong?

```
<?php
  session_start();
  $form_token = uniqid();
  $_SESSION['user_token'] = $form_token;
?>
<form method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="user_token" value="<?php echo  $_SESSION['user_token'];  ?>" />
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
<?php
  if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
  if ($_POST['user_token'] == $_SESSION['user_token']) {
     echo "TEST OK";
     unset($_SESSION['user_token']);
   } else {echo "Session Expired";}
}
?>
```

Comment: If you refresh your page, your $form_token will get a new value and put in the hidden input. So you will always have $_SESSION['user_token'] == $_POST['user_token']

Comment: Ok, but the output is always an expired session! Why? How i can correct it?

Comment: @stacks - it is because you are always generating a new token BEFORE comparing the $_SESSION and $_POST values. Check the code sample I've provided in the answer below

Comment: please read the code I modified ... if i make echo $ _POST ['user_token'] and echo $ _SESSION ['user_token'] i have 2 different values each time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to DeadLock I solved in that way

```
session_start();
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
    if($_SESSION['user_token'] == $_POST['user_token']) {
        unset($_SESSION['user_token']);
        $form_token = uniqid();
        $_SESSION['user_token'] = $form_token;
        include_once('./arrivi.php');
        include_once('./script/controlloarrivi.php');
        } else {
       header("location: ./2.php");
      }
    } else{
    $form_token = uniqid();
    $_SESSION['user_token'] = $form_token;
    include_once('./arrivi.php');
    }
?>
```

Now i have another problem! I need to reload            include_once('./arrivi.php'); when i press submit
But i have results in
include_once('./script/controlloarrivi.php');

How i can do that? I read that i need to use ajax necessarily! But how?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a few modifications to the ordering of your code.

```
<?php 
       session_start();
    // If this is a post request, you don't need to create a new session. Just check for the eixsting value.
    if (isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        if($_SESSION['user_token'] == $_POST['user_token']) {
            echo "TEST OK";
        } else { 
          echo "Session expired";
        }
    } else{ // Start a new session ONLY if this is the first time the user is entering this page.
       $form_token = uniqid();
       $_SESSION['user_token'] = $form_token;
    }

    include_once('./config.php');
?>
    <form method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="user_token" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['user_token'];?>" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
```

NOTE: This code block is only to help you figure out your double insertion issue (or rather the always 'expired session' output). However, this may not be the best way to implement sessions in PHP. You might want to read up more on [PHP Sessions](http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php). Check the examples given in the comments of the official documentation. This should give you a good idea about what you may beed,

Comment: Notice: Undefined variable: _SESSION in htdocs\b\1.php on line 13

Comment: You may have missed a $ before _SESSION while copying. Verify that.

Comment: No :( try it too! And whe i refresh page, it resend TEST OK not Session expired!

Comment: Oops! My bad! I copied your code as it. Updated it to 'echo' $_SESSION['user_token'] to the hidden input.

Comment: No, now i have same error as before but now it return always Session expired! (also the first submit!)

Comment: I want only prevent the double insertion...i don't need time session! It show always TEST OK with error Notice: Undefined variable: _SESSION in htdocs\b\1.php on line 13 and every time i try to refresh page the the session doesn't expire

Comment: There's a big difference between my code and the one that you are still using. You may want to try again.

Comment: yes, i don't know how it correctly write! But it don't work as i want!

Comment: You can copy-paste the complete code as it is and execute it.

Comment: Updated. 
           session_start(); had to go at the beginning of the code. You should move the complete PHP block even before your <html> tag as well!

Comment: Now it work correctly (only if I add    unset($_SESSION['user_token']); with TEST OK) but now i get other error when i try to refresh page! Notice: Undefined index: user_token in D:\xampp7\htdocs\b\1.php on line 14 Session expired